# Organic groups joining strategy

Tags: organic-groups, users

Does anyone know how I can force a user to register before being allowed to join an organic group?

Presently, my users receive a link which takes them to a page with a join button. Once they click on the button they are either added to the group as registered members or presented with an "error" message which states they need to register for anonymous users.

I would like to automate the process for those anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this go on to Configuration > Organic Groups >OG Global permissions and Uncheck the fields that u wish to hide from  non-members ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the Join button but not get an "error" (403 page), there are a couple modules out there that will instead giving an error message will bounce the visit directly to the login/register page.  Of those Login Toboggan and Redirect403ToLogin are most popular.  I'd recommend either - [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) has more options whereas [Redirect 403 To User Login](http://drupal.org/project/r4032login) does just this one thing - redirecting from 403 page to login page.  If you couple this with enabling the Organic Groups Registration module you'll save users a number of clicks.